# I want to install cudaminer but compile fails due to libcurl

Tags: dependencies

```
~/CudaMiner/./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/home/andreas/CudaMiner/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/home/andreas/CudaMiner/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 needs -traditional... no
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc -std=gnu99... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/endian.h usability... no
checking sys/endian.h presence... no
checking for sys/endian.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking whether be32dec is declared... no
checking whether le32dec is declared... no
checking whether be32enc is declared... no
checking whether le32enc is declared... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking whether we can compile AVX code... yes
checking whether we can compile XOP code... yes
checking whether we can compile AVX2 code... yes
checking for json_loads in -ljansson... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... yes
checking for EVP_DigestFinal_ex in -lcrypto... yes
./configure: line 6211: syntax error near unexpected token `,'
./configure: line 6211: `LIBCURL_CHECK_CONFIG(, 7.15.2, ,'
```

I tried to install libcurl but I get the following error:

```
~/CudaMiner/sudo apt-get -f install libcurl4-gnutls-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.32.0-1ubuntu1.3) but 7.33.0-1ubuntu1~ubuntu13.10.1~ppa1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I tried apt-get update  and apt-get install -f but no change.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f` and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry - did not work - same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it now with apitude

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then do:

```
sudo aptitude install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

I selected to downgrade the lib and now everything works.